# custom tumblr tags to create theme options for border color and border image

Tags: html, css, tumblr

I'm making a little tumblr theme and I'm hoping to create a customizable option for the user where they can either choose a `border-top` color and/or `border-image` ( and upload their own to the tumblr CDN ). I've got it to work with either/or, but not both.

In other words, I'd like for the default theme to come with a

`border-top: #somecolor;`

but they have the option to do

`border-image: url('funtime.png');`

The code should make it clear what I'm trying to do; it's just not working for some reason. Maybe a pro could help me out?

```
<meta name="image:top border" content="" />
<meta name="color:top border" content="#a64d00" />

body {
    border-top: 64px solid {color:top border};
    border-image: url('{image:top border}') 25% 25% 25% 25% repeat; 
}
```

I don't really know what else to do to get this to work. This way just gives the a blank space waiting to be occupied by an uploaded image. I take away the image option and the color works and vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have both sadly, its either `color` or `image`. Example: http://jsbin.com/kobicodu/1/edit

As `border-image` was the last property declared and has a valid image it overrides the shorthand `border-top` color.

More info: http://css-tricks.com/understanding-border-image/